# macos bash seems to ignore elif and only the first if statement works as intended

Tags: bash, macos, ping

I've been struggling trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I put a bit of code together to help with pinging our servers which works great, however it only prints weather or not the node is up and unless you have the ip's memorized need to lookup which server it goes to. So recently I decided I'd update it so it would print out a different string if for each node, the first one works great but for the second node (using elif) in the example it seems to skip it causing it to say the node is down.

I assume it's something do with how I went about adding multiple conditions to "test"
I've tried a few different ways I've found posted for adding conditions but they've had issues too.

Here's my code snippet:

```
DIR="/path/to/working/directory"
PING_SERVERS() {
tput smso
echo "`tput setaf 3` Pinging Servers... `tput setaf 7`"
tput rmso
sleep 1
#######
cat $DIR/servers.txt |  while read output
do
    ping -c 2 -t 2 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [[ "$output" == "10.5.0.13" ]] && [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "`tput setaf 2` node "$output" is up //Server1`tput setaf 7`"
  elif [[ "$output" == "10.5.0.30" ]] && [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "`tput setaf 2` node "$output" is up //Server2`tput setaf 7`"
  else
    echo "`tput setaf 1` node "$output" is down `tput setaf 7`"
    fi
done

echo " Done pinging servers"
}
PING_SERVERS

echo ""
ping -c 2 -t 2 10.5.0.13 #just to show they are up while debuging
sleep 2
echo ""
ping -c 2 -t 2 10.5.0.30 #just to show they are up while debuging
sleep 5
exit
```

here's what it gives me in the terminal:

```
 Pinging Servers...
 node 10.5.0.13 is up //Server1
 node 10.5.1.30 is down

Done pinging servers
PING 10.5.0.13 (10.5.0.13): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.5.0.13: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.731 ms
64 bytes from 10.5.0.13: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.382 ms

--- 10.5.0.13 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.731/2.557/3.382/0.825 ms

PING 10.5.0.30 (10.5.0.30): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.5.0.30: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.151 ms
64 bytes from 10.5.0.30: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.783 ms

--- 10.5.0.30 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 2.151/2.467/2.783/0.316 ms
```

Any help appreciated.
Jason

Comment: Also to clarify, I'm trying to ping using a list of addresses instead of just putting them in the script with a custom echo message for each because I have about 50 nodes and would rather keep the script somewhat readable.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing it to not match; try putting `set -x` before the relevant section to see what's happening. I do see some problems: the `[[ $? -eq 0 ]]` bits are testing the result of what's immediately before them (i.e. the `[[ "$output" == "10.5.0.13" ]]`, not the `ping`). Also, in several places the double-quotes around `$output` are actually *un*quoting it (not what you want); see [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: Another thing: since you have to have an `if` condition for each server, the file doesn't seem to be saving you anything. I'd either have the file hold both IPs and names (and read it with e.g. `while read serverIP serverName`), or make a function to ping a single server, pass the IP and name as arguments, then just have a bunch of calls to that function.

Comment: You are comparing and demonstrating that `10.5.0.30` is up, but your loop is instead pinging `10.5.1.30`. The third number is `0` vs `1`

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@that other guy
Guessed I should have refreshed, you were correct I messed it up while trying to get it working, thank you.

*Insert facepalm here*, I figured it out. As it turns out it was just user error caused by me staring at it for too long making me go blind to it.

After rereading my original post a couple times trying to troubleshoot more I realised the second host the elif was checking for is not the same host I was trying to ping in the file.

The first host is 10.5.0.13 so I assumed my second host I wanted to check for was 10.5.0.30 and set my elif statement to check for that. However it turns out (as you can see in the terminal output I posted) it's actually 10.5.1.30!

If I hadn't posted the question I probably wouldn't have been able to figure it out, (though now I can never show my face here again). Thanks for the syntax suggestions I will clean my code up a bit.

Thanks again,
Jason